# How to get the count of loaded rows into BigQuery through csv

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am loading a csv file into BigQuery through Python and as per the logging mechanism, I would like to print the number of rows been loaded into the BigQuery table partitioned on Day

The code that I am using below gives the count of the entire table but I want the count of rows for each day which means for each current partition.

So if yesterday I loaded `2 rows` and today I loaded `3 rows` then 
`destination_table.num_rows = 5 (total count)`

but I want 3 , the number of rows loaded in the current Day partition only

```py
 destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table("{stg_table_1}".format(stg_table_1=self.projconfig.stg_table_1)))
        print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to check the result of your load job by using

`load_job.result() # wait for the job to finish
load_job.output_rows`

instead of querying the destination table after the data was loaded.
Documentation [here](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJob.output_rows.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJob.output_rows)

LE: Or documentation here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJob.html

Comment: I don't want to run a query job for this, rather I would prefer to get the loaded rows during the load process itself in order to know how many rows got loaded by the current run

Comment: You can do that by using num_dml_affected_rows from the current run.

Comment: I got this error print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_dml_affected_rows))
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'num_dml_affected_rows'

Comment: This is an attribute of the QueryJob that loads the data. I imagine you have something like `job = client.query(query)` and then you can use  `job.num_dml_affected_rows`

Comment: I am not using Query Job as I am loading from csv  ``` client = bigquery.Client() load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
            self.uri, dataset_ref.table(self.stg_table),
            job_config=job_config
        )  # API request  ```

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @MitchellTracy I updated the answer with a new link.